# Pointer Errors in C++

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I have a std::vector type that holds pointers to objects within my application. The declaration for which looks like this:

```
std::vector< PIXEL* > stgPixels;
```

...where PIXEL is a struct that is defined in my application( consists of 2 floating point variables ).

EDIT: To add a pixel to vector:

```
// allocate a new pixel
PIXEL *pPixel = new PIXEL( D3DXVECTOR2( x, y ) );

// store pixel
stgPixels.push_back( pPixel );
```

During runtime I am receiving an unhandled exception error concerning the memory location of specific PIXEL pointers...I have done some debugging...the PIXEL object resides at the same location as it did when allocated...the problem seems to be the std::vector object. Somehow, the memory address stored in the vector changes to some arbitrary location that cannot be cast to my PIXEL type...causing an exception...

What may be happening in my application that would cause the value in the std::vector object to become invalid? This vector stores a number of pixels all at one time and is no longer altered afterwards...I am very careful about changing the value of items within the array...

Comment: Please paste code of adding elements to vector.

Comment: "What may be happening in my application that would cause the value in the std::vector object to become invalid?" multiple deallocation is the most common culprit. Run with valgrind to see what happens.

Comment: Just a guess: are you storing temporary objects instead of using `new`?

Comment: Good point, @awesomeyi, hope you don't mind if I add that to the list in my answer.

Comment: no definitely storing objects allocated with 'new'...they are managed and destroyed when the application is finished...no sooner! I can validate that the object has not been destroyed because i have multiple pointers to the same PIXEL object...One is good but the pointer within the array becomes invalid...

Comment: We could skip a lot of guesswork if you gave us a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: do you guys work on commission or something?

Comment: No, everyone on StackOverflow volunteers their time to help others.  What goes around comes around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are certain that the actual pointer values in the vector have changed (*ie* you have verified this by outputting the pointer values to console or file, both before and after), then something is trashing your vector.  Otherwise you've probably freed that memory.

**If the pointer values have changed, some common scenarios are:**

- a buffer overrun (or similar undefined behaviour) has overwritten some or all of the vector data;
- a buffer overrun (or similar undefined behaviour) has overwritten the vector itself, or the vector is part of an object that has been destroyed;
- race conditions in multi-threaded environments - you may need locking to ensure atomic access to the vector;
- a logic error in your program messed up the vector while doing an operation on it;
- you've done something nasty and corrupted the heap.

**If the pointer values have *not* changed, then some common scenarios are:**

- you have already returned your `PIXEL` object(s) to the OS somewhere (perhaps deleted in a destructor);
- the `PIXEL` object(s) were defined on the stack and have since been destroyed (*ie* storing pointer to temporary object);
- you've done something nasty and corrupted the heap.

Comment: I definitely have not freed the memory...I can access the PIXEL object using a pointer stored in a different location( an array or vector )...

Comment: this was the answer i was looking for just general info on why this problem may occur...I'll debug further and try to expose the problem...